# How to redirect a user in angular.js using access token mechanism?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, authorization, token

This is the process flow:

1. On the front end, the user logs in by providing username and password.
2. The server will respond a token to the user if the credentials are correct.
3. Now the user should be redirected to the homepage (PROBLEM HERE). I have set the token in the header by this code:  $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = token;
4. Also, when I do a http.get method, I am getting an "OK" response

   ```
   $http({ method: 'GET',

       url: '/home/',

       headers: {
           'X-Auth-Token': token
       }
   }).then(function successCallback(response) {
       console.log(response.statusText);
   }
   ```

Now, the issue is that when I use $window.location.href = "/home", the server responds "unauthorized token" because the server always expects a token in the header with each request. In the command window.location.href, I cannot set the header.

What is an alternative to redirect the user to the homepage. Assume the server always checks the header for the access token.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If i understood u right is the homepage ('/home') not part of your current angular single-page application (u are not setting this route by `ngRoute` or `angular-ui-router`)?

Comment: yes, i am not setting this by ngRoute or angular-ui-router.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK if u are using HTTP redirect like setting the window.location.href, there is no way to custom headers. Neither can u do that when using a form post.Use cookies instead for these purpose.

Ajax(XMLhttpRequest) may be the only one that supports setting custom headers.

If u don't mind using angular routing(however doing this may expose some logic in js code which should only be exposed to authenticated user), u may add an `resolve` for `resolveRedirectTo` in which make an ajax request to check the authentication status every time route changes.

EDIT

---

For using angular routing, the basic thinking is to ask user to do send ajax request with custom headers to server to check if he/she is authorized to visit that page. Check out the following code and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmhuntermax/akbcrucb/4/)

```
app
.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl:"home.html" ,
        controller: 'MainController',
        resolve:{
            isLogin:function($q, $http,$location) {
              var deferred = $q.defer();
              //verify the user via an ajax request every time the user attempts to visit `/home`
              //here since u have already set the custom headers for $http upon signing in, the next request will be with the header.
              //the follow test url will return {isLogin:true}
              $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://echo.jsontest.com/isLogin/true'})
                  .success(function(data) {


                      if(data.isLogin){
                        deferred.resolve(data.isLogin); //  no need to redirect
                      }
                      else{
                        $location.path("/guest");// redirect to guest page if not authorized
                        deferred.reject(); 
                      }
                  })
                  .error(function(data){
                  //error
                      $location.path("/guest");
                      deferred.reject();
                  });

              return deferred.promise;  
          }
        }
    }).
    when("/guest",{
        templateUrl: "guest.html",
      controller: 'GuestController',
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/guest'})
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I didn't understand much of it. Can you give me any url example that will enable me to visualize this in a better way?

Comment: I've updated my answer and hope it will be of some help.